# Format Hexadecimal String in PHP

Tags: php, format, hex

I have for example this string

```
0A
```

Or

```
A001
```

Or

```
AC000001
```

I need final format to be like that, No matter if number 1,2,3 or even 6 digits.

```
00-00-00-01
```

Any ideas to do this in PHP ?

Comment: Take a look at `wordwrap()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<?php
    $hexstring = "0A";

    //Pad string to correct lenght "0A" = "0000000A".
    $hexstring = str_pad($hexstring, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

    //Split into groups of two. ["00","00","00","0A"].      
    $hexstring = str_split($hexstring, 2);

    //Merge together with hyphens. "00-00-00-0A".
    $hexstring = implode("-", $hexstring);
?>
```

This code could also be condensed into this:

```
<?php
    $hexstring = "0A";
    $hexstring = implode("-", str_split(str_pad($hexstring, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT), 2));
?>
```

This code will first pad the incoming string to the correct length. So no matter if the string is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 or 8 characters long it will be padded with zeroes to become exactly 8 characters long.

After padding the string will be split into groups of two characters each and then joined back together with hyphens inbetween.